# question on redirecting in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, redirect, web-applications

i am using gwt to create a web application.

when  a user presses the logout button, i want to be able to refresh the page(or basically redirect to the homepage)as my GWT application runs only on one html page.

what is the programmatic code to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [Window.Location.assign()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#assign(java.lang.String)) to tell the browser to go to a URL, such as a URL pointing to a servlet that logs out the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

//redirect the browser to the given url. Native method

```
public static native void redirect(String url)/*-{
      $wnd.location = url;
  }-*/;
```

//Example call

```
redirect("http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: Actually, even in JS the correct method would be `$wnd.location.assign(url)` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) -- which happens to be exactly what GWT's `Window.Location.assign()` does (see Window.java here: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ line 130)